# How to enumerate all the MBeans for a JDK?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am wondering whether I can enumerate all the `MBeans` getting from `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [queryMBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#queryMBeans%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.QueryExp%29) method on the MBeanServerConnection to list all the beans on a service (just pass null in for both parameters).

To do that using `ManagementFactory`, call
 `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().queryMBeans(null,null);`